# Generate output file in linux C++

Tags: c++, linux, file-io

i'm using Linux & C++, below there is the only output function in the entire program.
For some reason the output file "Network_Managment_Output.txt"
is not generated, when using Visual Basic in Windows it works perfectly !

i cannot figure out why the output file isn't generated i don't get any errors due.

```
void Data_list :: print_msg (Data_list* head) const             
{

Data_list* start = head;

FILE* fp=fopen("Network_Managment_Output.txt","w");

while(start!=NULL)
{
    fprintf(fp, "%s\n",start->message);                 //Printing messages to output file
    start=start->Next;
}
fclose(fp);
}
```

if i replace : `fprintf(fp, "%s\n",start->message);`
with  `cout<<start->message<<endl;`

it's prints out the data to the screen perfectly.

Any Advice ????

Comment: You get no errors because you don't check for errors.

Comment: What is the type of `message`?

Comment: If the file fails to open, I'm surprised it allows the fprintf without a seg fault. You can fprintf to NULL as a no-op? Ok, technically it's UB but I'd expect a seg-fault.

Comment: Please compile with `g++ -Wall -g` and learn how to use the debugger `gdb` and the memory leak detector `valgrind`

Comment: also you may use `strace` with you executable to quick find out whats happened with `open()` -- it will shows you an error code...

Comment: Despite the presence of **some** errors in this code, I am not convinced it contains **the** error. Please reduce your original program to the smallest possible program that still displays the error. Then copy-paste that program into your question. See http://sscce.org for more info.

Comment: i've tried to flush the FILE*, but i didn't help.
Also replaced fprintf with fputs, 
all ! changes work perfectly in Visual Basic but in Linux the output file stays empty
:(

Answer (score 3):

Replace this line:

```
FILE* fp=fopen("Network_Managment_Output.txt","w");
```

with

```
FILE* fp=fopen("Network_Managment_Output.txt","w");
if(!fp) perror("Network_Management_Output.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems issue is with ur code or compile (configuration or any), I made the code blow from the code hint u have provided and it is working fine take a look

Do something like that, include these libraries and save file (x).cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct Data_list{
   char message[250];
   Data_list *Next;
};

void print_msg (Data_list* head){
    Data_list* start = head;

    FILE *fp = NULL;
    fp = fopen("Network_Managment_Output.txt","w");
    if (fp != NULL){
        while(start!=NULL){
            fprintf(fp, "%s\n",start->message);                 //Printing messages to output file
            start=start->Next;
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
}

int main(){
  Data_list* start = (struct Data_list *)malloc(sizeof(struct Data_list)) ;
  strcpy(start->message,"test 1");
  start->Next = (struct Data_list *)malloc(sizeof(struct Data_list)) ;
  strcpy(start->Next->message,"test 2");
  start->Next->Next = NULL;
  print_msg(start);

  return 0;
}
```

output in file is

```
 test 1 
 test 2
```

Comment: Thanks.. i've made a few changes in the program

this line : 
**FILE *fp = NULL;
  fp = fopen("Network_Managment_Output.txt","w"); **


now apears in the main.cpp
and the file is created, but no output for some reason
the output function is now

**void Data_list :: print_msg (Data_list* head,FILE* fp)    //Printing messages
{
 Data_list* start = head;
 
 while(start!=NULL)
 {
  cout<<start->message<<endl;
  fprintf(fp, "%s\n",start->message);     //Printing messages to output file
  start=start->Next;
 }
}

Comment: I am not able to see any issue , if u can able to post ur code ...i mean what are you doing now may be i can help, because the code i sent you is working..Copy this code and create a new project(or file test.cpp in a separate folder  ) and compile / run it and the give me the list for error ,(copy them) from console.